# How to prove by induction that $|\sin(nx)| \leq n|\sin x|$?

Tags: trigonometry

Here $n$ belongs to natural numbers. Firstly, I proved the relation by putting $n = 1$ . Then, taking $$|\sin(mx)| \leq m|\sin x|$$ true, I had to prove $$|\sin(m + 1)x| \leq (m + 1)|\sin x|$$  Now, here I got stuck. How to prove it?? Please help.

Comment: What's the addition formula, $\sin (a+b) =\;?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The inductive step:** Using the triangle inequality and the fact that $\sin$ and $\cos$ function are bounded by $1$ we get

$$|\sin((n+1)x)|=|\sin(nx)\cos x+\cos(nx)\sin(x)|\le|\sin(nx)|\cos(x)|+|\cos(nx)||\sin(x)|\\\le|\sin(nx)|+|\sin(x)|\le n|\sin(x)|+|\sin(x)|=(n+1)|\sin(x)|$$

Comment: It is worth noting that the expression, $sin(n \cdot x) \leq n \cdot sin(x)$ (without modulus) on the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, is also true and for similar reasoning, but with the additional fact that 
$(k+1) \cdot sin(x) > k \cdot sin(x) \geq 0$, $\forall x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}], \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.